# I need help! I have been trying to write a Java program that will print out the largest prime factor of a given number determined by user input

Tags: java, primes

> This is my code so far but I am having trouble. I tried to create an array with all the prime
> factors and print the last index of the array but I having trouble figuring out the length the array should be. Am I doing this all wrong? Is there a better method?(New to stack overflow)(still learning java).

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc.nextInt(); //Given Number
        sc.close();
        int n = 0;
        int [] PrimeFactors = new int[num];
        for(int i = 1; n < PrimeFactors.length; i++)
        {
            if(checkPrime(i) == false && num % i == 0)
            {
                PrimeFactors[n] = i;
                n++;
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(PrimeFactors[PrimeFactors.length - 1]);
    }
    
    public static boolean checkPrime(int a)
    {
        boolean bool = false;
        if(true)
        {
            for(int i = 2; i <= a / 2; i++)
            {
                if(a % i == 0)
                {
                    bool = true;break;
                }
            }
        }
        return bool;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try with an ArrayList intead of an array, so you don't have to bother about the size of it.

Comment: Note you track the index of found primes in `n`